# What happens if size_t is signed like -1

Tags: c

If `size_t` is signed like -1 is incorrect the code?

For example in this `strncat` implementation at the end of function size_t is -1. Can overflow?

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *util_strncat(char *destination, const char *source, size_t len) {
   char *temp = destination + strlen(destination);

   while (len--) {
      *temp++ = *source++;
      if(*source == '\0'){
         break;
      }
   }
   *temp = '\0';

   printf("%zu\n",len); //-1

   return destination;
}

int main() {
   char dest[7] = "abcd";
   char src[] = "efg";
   util_strncat(dest, src, 2);
   printf("%s\n", dest);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what happens if size_t is signed like -1 (?)

If code truly printed a `"-1"`, then the compilation is not C compliant.

> in this `strncat` implementation at the end of function size_t is -1.

No it is not -1 with a conforming C compiler.

`size_t` is an *unsigned* integer of some width - at least 16 bits.

`while (len--) {` loop continues until `len == 0`.  With the post decrement `len--`, the value after the evaluation wraps around to `SIZE_MAX`, some large positive value.

> Can overflow?

Mathematically yes `size_t` math can overflow. In C *unsigned* math is well defined to wrap around<sup>1</sup>, in effect modulo `SIZE_MAX + 1` for type `size_t`. §6.2.5 9

---

I'd expect `printf("%zu\n",len);` to report `18446744073709551615`, `4294967295` or some other [Mersenne number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html).

> `size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator;  C11dr §7.19 2

---

<sup>1</sup> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

---

**Questionable code**

Consider `util_strncat(ptr, "", size)` can lead to *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
int main() {
   char dest[7] = "abcd";
   char src[] = "\0xyz";
   util_strncat(dest, src, 2);
   printf("%s\n", dest);
   printf("%c\n", dest[5]); // 'x'!!
}
```

Comment: There is also the POSIX `ssize_t` type; a function returning this type _could_ return -1, but `%zu` wouldn't print `"-1"` here either.

Comment: @DavidBowling AFAIK, POSIX does not even require `ssize_t` to be the same width as `size_t`.  It usually is the same, yet I think it may be allowed to be wider.

Comment: I thought that `ssize_t` has to be wider than `size_t`, because it has to be able to represent all `size_t` values, in addition to -1 (at least). But, I'll have to check to see if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: @DavidBowling IIRC, `ssize_t` is not required to represent all `size_t` either.  It certainly usually handles `[-1...SIZE_MAX/2]` at least.

Comment: @DavidBowling, chux is correct.  POSIX does not link `ssize_t` with `size_t` in any formal way.  They have different, independent descriptions, and different, independent maximum values given in `limits.h` and `stdint.h`, respectively.  It is often the case in practice that the two are the same size, but this is not required.  I have never knowingly used an implementation where `size_t`  was smaller than `ssize_t`, though this is allowed, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- thanks... all I could find in the POSIX Standard is: "The type **ssize_t** shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]." But no connection between `size_t` and `ssize_t` widths. Hmmm. Dementia?

Answer (score 0):

The `%zu` cant print the negative number at any circumstances. When unsigned number of the type `size_t` wraps over when decreasing its value becomes `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: This answer presents two correct, but uncorrelated, facts.  `%zu` will not format the corresponding value with a negative sign because the `u` says to interpret it as an unsigned number.  The value (as interpreted according to any particular type) or bit pattern of the corresponding argument doesn't matter in that regard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger did I write that they are?. You could also add the president Trump's headache is not correlated with unsigned wrap around :) and numbers of printf calls in the software used by the WH.

Comment: Although you did not explicitly say that the two facts are correlated, that is an implication of juxtaposing them in the way that you did.  If they are not meant to be rhetorically connected then this answer would benefit from a few more words to make that clear.